# what does `IgnoredMulti` statistic for Udp in debian linux mean?

Tags: linux, debian, udp, multicast

I have a Ubuntu machine that is receiving UDP packets by joining a multicast group, occasionally we are getting UDP packet drops.
when I am trying to monitor using `netstat -s` I get the following output

```
Udp:
    5075891768 packets received
    360 packets to unknown port received.
    0 packet receive errors
    5686798 packets sent
    RcvbufErrors: 0
    IgnoredMulti: 274908
```

there is no RcvbufErrors or InErrors, but I can see the `IgnoredMulti` field increasing in size, whenever a packet is missed. But I am not able to find what the field means and when does it increase.

Comment: Cross posting https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70696331/what-does-ignoredmulti-statistic-for-udp-in-debian-linux-mean

Comment: My guess: These are multicast packets that were received for groups you're not subscribed to, so they were ignored.

Comment: @GAD3R Cross-post at SO was removed in the meantime.